# React Native || Change Screen Orientation using expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I am trying to change the ScreenOrientation of the device when the user click on a button in the app, I searched the documentation but I did not found anything useful, would you please share your ideas or at least where can I start in order for me to get this working.

Tools Used: React Native || Expo

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the lockAsync function?

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationlockasyncorientationlock

I think that you can trigger the function with an onPress event.

It belongs to the expo-screen-orientation package and you can specify the orientation you want.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP is looking a way to lock the screen orientation, rather he is trying to change it when a button is clicked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be like a workaround locking the screen to a certain orientation when the button is pressed? If the OP doesn't lock the orientation it may change if the device is rotated.